# How to deploy OpenLayers with Tomcat + JSF 2

Tags: javascript, tomcat, openlayers

I'm trying to get OpenLayers deployed in my JSF 2.0 App on tomcat.

So far, What I did was to copy `openLayers.js` to the `resources` directory of the web app (I have other JS working from there successfully) and the `theme` and `img` directories in to the same `resources` directory.

Next, I included `openLayers.js` from my `xhtml` file as follows:

```
<h:outputScript library="js" name="openLayers.js" />
```

When I try to use `OpenLayers` I get these errors on the `Javascript` console:

```
BaseTypes.jsGET https://ben.serveraddress.com:8443/MDPortal/lib/OpenLayers/BaseTypes.js 404 (Not Found)
Class.jsGET https://ben.serveraddress.com:8443/MDPortal/lib/OpenLayers/BaseTypes/Class.js 404 (Not Found)
Util.jsGET https://ben.serveraddress.com:8443/MDPortal/lib/OpenLayers/Util.js 404 (Not Found)
Element.jsGET https://ben.serveraddress.com:8443/MDPortal/lib/OpenLayers/BaseTypes/Element.js 404 (Not Found)
Bounds.jsGET https://ben.serveraddress.com:8443/MDPortal/lib/OpenLayers/BaseTypes/Bounds.js 404 (Not Found)
LonLat.jsGET https://ben.serveraddress.com:8443/MDPortal/lib/OpenLayers/BaseTypes/LonLat.js 404 (Not Found)
Pixel.jsGET https://ben.serveraddress.com:8443/MDPortal/lib/OpenLayers/BaseTypes/Pixel.js 404 (Not Found)
Size.jsGET https://ben.serveraddress.com:8443/MDPortal/lib/OpenLayers/BaseTypes/Size.js 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: Try renaming openLayers.js -> OpenLayers.js. And better use single file version in production.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
<h:outputScript library="js" name="http://openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js" />
```

Or else make sure you copy `/build/OpenLayers.js` to your `/lib`.

Oh, and **don't forget** to copy `/theme` and `/img` directories as well.

Comment: Thanks! I'm using JSF 2 with the `resources/js/` folder (where all my javascript files are). I don't have a `/lib` folder so not sure where it should be.

Comment: Just copy the file and directories to `resources/js/`

Comment: Ok. So that's actually what I tried originally and didn't work.

Comment: Originally you did not copy `/build/OpenLayers.js` to `resources/js/`, you copied `/OpenLayers.js` (which is not the single file version and requires `/lib` files)