# Including Openlayer.js in JSF 2.1 Project

Tags: jsf, openlayers

I am trying to include OpenLayers.js in JSF project.

`<h:outputScript library="js" name="OpenLayers.js"  target="head"/>`

1. I didn't have any resources folder so I created one and added openlayers.js and other folder as this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6561944/how-to-deploy-openlayers-with-tomcat-jsf-2) tells.
2. I also tried to put it into lib folder
   But I always get:

[image]

> script type="text/javascript" src="RES_NOT_FOUND

Do I need to do additional configuration to run this js library?

Answer (score 1):

We have the same problem. OpenLayers.js calculate the script location URI and based on this location include the other components like styles etc.

So it we use option 1 the JS is well included but there are broken link to CSS and IMAGES. 
As a temporary solution we are using now the second option and it works well.

```
1: <h:outputScript library="js/openlayers" name="OpenLayers.js" />
2: <script src="resources/js/openlayers/OpenLayers.js"></script>
```

The cause is that JSF overrides the link so OpenLayers.js.xhtml does not match the regexp anymore: 
http://HOST/CONTEXT/javax.faces.resource/OpenLayers.js.xhtml?ln=js/openlayers

It's not a problem to use the option2 as long as you don't something like MapConponent in a jar.